# How can I print a dollar symbol inside(or before) the input box?

Tags: html

The field below retrieves hourly pay rate from user input. How can I display a "$" sign inside (or before) the input field where the user types in the hourly pay rate?

```
<tr>
<td>Hourly Pay Rate</td>
<td><input type = "number" name = "HPR" min="0" step="0.01"  required></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Using CSS or HTML? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Before the input field? By writing it to the HTML?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML text input field with currency symbol](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2913236/html-text-input-field-with-currency-symbol)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you are asking for :

first one will just put a "$"sign before the input type

```
<tr>
<td>Hourly Pay Rate</td>
<td>$<input type = "number" name = "HPR" min="0" step="0.01"  required></td>
</tr>
```

second one will put a "$" inside the input type and will disappear once user start typing.

```
<tr>
<td>Hourly Pay Rate</td>
<td><input type = "number" placeholder="$" name = "HPR" min="0" step="0.01"  required></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 13):

```css
.dollar{
 display:inline-block;
 position: relative;
 }
.dollar input{
 padding-left:15px;
 }
.dollar:before {
 position: absolute;
    content:"$";
    left:5px;
 top:2px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="dollar"><input type="number"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.dollar::before {
    content: "$";
    padding: 0 5px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="dollar">
<input type ="text">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Before input box you can try this:

`<td>Hourly Pay Rate($):</td>
 <td><input type = "number" name = "HPR" min="0" step="0.01"  required></td>`