# How to automatically add USD after input in contact form 7

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create an input box that allow users to enter currency amount. I have created a text box in contact form 7, but it should automatically add "USD" at the end, as soon as someone enters the digit into the input box.

If it's not possible, USD written at the end of the input field would be fine too.

Comment: You need to use jquery for it. Or if only html and css look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/2913366/3697102

Comment: Is it a `required` field?

Comment: @Shaggy yes! It's a required field

Comment: Contact Form 7 allows you to add your own html to the form in WordPress. Is there a reason you haven't simply put "USD" next to the form field there?

Answer (score 2):

As it is a `required` field, you can achieve this by adding a tag containing the "USD" text immediately after the `input` and set its `display` to `none` while the `input` is empty using the `:invalid` [pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes):

```css
#input:invalid+span{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<input id="input" required type="number" value=""><span>USD</span>
```