# how to add dollar($) symbol to @Html.TextBoxFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

How can i add dollar symbol to the mvc value

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.RefundAmount, new { @class = "form-control", id = "RefundAmount", name = "RefundAmount",disabled="disabled" })
```

Comment: Where you want to add `$` symbol?

Comment: Before value in the text box

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to do.. If you want currency formatting for which '$' should not be removed then put it outside of textbox as a simple solution. If it is just text you want to display you can simply append '$' in front of the text you display in textbox.

Comment: Refer neat CSS trick from [this SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2913236/html-text-input-field-with-currency-symbol)

Answer (score 1):

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.RefundAmount, new { @class = "required numeric", Value=String.Format("$ {0}",Model.RefundAmount) })
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

Add to view :
*put $ sign between i tags

```
<div class="input-icon">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Sample,new {htmlAttributes = new { @class ="txt form control"} })
    <i>$</i>  ($ sign between the i tags)                   
</div>                 
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Sample, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

css:

```
.input-icon {
    position: relative;
}

.input-icon > i {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    transform: translate(0, -50%);
    top: 50%;
    pointer-events: none;
    width: 35px;
    text-align: center;
    font-style: normal;
}

.input-icon > input {
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 0;
}
```

for more details check [link here](https://jsfiddle.net/q6Lmqh8h/634/)

Answer (score -1):

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => "$"+x.RefundAmount, new { @class = "form-control", id = "RefundAmount", name = "RefundAmount",disabled="disabled" })
```

Try this above code

Comment: Your post is not clear. Please explain it very clearly