# How do I add a dollar symbol in front of a TextBox (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

How do I add a dollar sign in front of the TextBox of Rate, based on this code? I want to have the dollar symbol so people don't need to type '$' by themselves. Here is my code:

```
<div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 20px">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        @Html.Label("lblP1", "Rate 1", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label", @style = "margin-right: 30px" })
        <br />
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Pricing.Price1, null, new { htmlAttributes = new { @type = "string", @class = "form-control" } })
        <br />
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Pricing.Price1, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        @Html.Label("lblExp1", "Expiry 1", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label", @style = "margin-right: 30px" })
        <br />
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Pricing.Exp1, "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", new { htmlAttributes = new { @type = "text", @class = "form-control datepicker1", @id = "datepicker1", @placeholder = "MM/DD/YYYY" } })
    </div>
</div>
```

It looks like:

[image]

Comment: you can add add EditFor into span like `<span class="currencyinput">$@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Pricing.Price1, null, new { htmlAttributes = new { @type = "string", @class = "form-control" } })
            <br /></span>`

Comment: You can also use javascript, Jquery or any frontend language to render it on keystrokes/typing

Comment: Please refer to this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_form_input_group&stacked=h)

Comment: Relevant Answer `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2913236/html-text-input-field-with-currency-symbol`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [DisplayFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayformatattribute?view=netframework-4.8) attribute to decorate your model property:

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:c}")]
public decimal Price1 { get; set; }
```

Then in your view:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Pricing.Price1)
```

You could apply similar formatting for the expiry DateTime using DisplayFormat.

---

Or instead of `EditorFor` you could use `TextBoxFor` passing in a format string:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Pricing.Price1, "{0:c}")
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're already using Bootstrap. You could use the [Input group](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/input-group/) to render a dollar sign in front of the input like so:

```
<div class="input-group mb-3">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
       <span class="input-group-text">$</span>
    </div>
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Pricing.Price1, null, new { htmlAttributes = new { @type = "string", @class = "form-control" } })
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Bootrap 4 and fontawesome

```
  <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Pricing.Price1, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label font-weight-bold" })
                    <div>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1"><i class="fas fa-dollar-sign"></i></span>
                            </div>
                           @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Pricing.Price1, "{0:c}")
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Pricing.Price1, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```