# Remove the up/down increment/decrement buttons on number inputs using CSS

Tags: html, css

How can you remove the up/down increment/decrement buttons on number inputs using `CSS`?

I want to do this to a number input for money, as the arrows interfere with the currency symbol that I have added as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28337887/15159198) SO answer.

[image: number input increment/decrement arrows interfering with currency sign]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following `CSS` code will remove the arrows on *all* inputs:

```css
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button { 
  -webkit-appearance: none; 
  margin: 0; 
}
```

This can be modified to:

```css
.money input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
.money input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button { 
  -webkit-appearance: none; 
  margin: 0; 
}
```

Which will only modify the inputs that are contained in an element with the class `money`, in case you want to use some other number inputs *with* the increment/decrement arrows.

[image: Solution]

Comment: It mess up with [maxLength] attribute. If I do that as you have mentioned in CSS the HTML part [maxLength] does not work.

Answer (score 2):

The following CSS will work for most browsers. The following method will allow you to use it as a text box with only numbers allowed. Also, This method allows you to copy-paste only numbers(it removes alphabets and keeps numbers when you paste) in the box without any extra line of coding.

Simply you have to apply the class name `number-to-text` to the input box.

```
<input type="number" value="5" class="number-to-text">
```

Add following CSS

```
input.number-to-text::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input.number-to-text::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0;
}

input[type=number].number-to-text {
    -moz-appearance: textfield;
}
```

The following jquery code will disable the number input spin button behaviour (disable increment/decrement numbers by pressing the up and down arrow keys).

```
$('input.number-to-text').keydown(function(event) {
    if ([38, 40].indexOf(event.keyCode) > -1) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```