# How to align text inside a placeholder

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a input type text where placeholder having two values like (English and spanish). 
but i want english text to be left align and spanish text should be right align but in my case i am doing this like .

```
Example:

<input type="text" nam="name" placeholder="Name&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Nombre" >
```

> I am doing like this using nbsp but when i open this on another window
>   or in responsive mode text getting outside or not aligned.
>       so how can i align text inside placeholder to left and right please help me related this ..

Comment: `<input type="text" nam="name" placeholder="Name       Nombre" >`use space instead of `&nbsp;`

Comment: I want space between them .. thats why i am having this issue

Comment: Do — not — use `placeholder`. It is bad User Experience. People cannot see where they type. After starting to type. Use a `label`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [text-align: right; only for placeholder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6729837/text-align-right-only-for-placeholder)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shruti

Check solution

```
If you satisfied please give me vote as a gift :)
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input").click(function(){
   $("label").hide();
  });
  $("input").focusout(function(){
         if($(this).val() !=''){
    
    } else{
     $("label").show();
    }
    
    
     });
 });
```

```css
p{position: relative; display: inline-block;}
 label[for="english"] { position: absolute;left: 4px;}
 label[for="spanish"] {position: absolute; right: 4px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
<label for="english">Name </label>
<label for="spanish">Nombre</label>
<input type="text" nam="name">
</p>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this with pure html and css, a workaround would be using js, and faking a placeholder behavior with css.. like the example..

```js
var input = document.getElementById("name");

input.onblur = function() {
   if(!input.value) input.classList.remove('not-empty');
};

input.onfocus = function() {
   input.classList.add('not-empty');
};
```

```css
.input-container {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.input-container:before {
    content: "name";
    position: absolute;
    left: 5px;
    top: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}

.input-container:after {
    content: "nombre";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 5px;
    z-index: -1;
}

.input-container input {
    z-index: 1;
    background: transparent;
}

.input-container input.not-empty {
    background: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-container"><input id="name" type="text" name="name"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the cleanest way is this :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input').focus(function() {
    $('label').addClass("focus");
  })
  $('input').blur(function() {
    if(!$(this).val()) {
      $('label').removeClass("focus");
    }
  })
});
```

```css
.input-group {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

label {
  pointer-events: none;
}

label.focus {
  display: none;
}

label.english {
  position: absolute;
  left: 4px;
}

label.spanish {
  position: absolute;
  right: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-group">
  <label class="english" for="name">Name</label>
  <label class="spanish" for="name">Nombre</label>
  <input id="name" type="text" name="name">
</div>
```

[Why you should use label ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7636502/why-use-label)
&
[Some docs about multiple label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829936/can-an-input-field-have-two-labels)

Comment: If you're going to do it this way you should set a rule on the `label` for the pointer-events property value to be none. Without this you have to click within the whitespace between the labels which is somewhat of a poor user experience.

Comment: You should add the js code to change the visibility of the `labels` to hidden when the input has focus and when it has text inside it.

Comment: This is a misuse of the `for` attribute on labels... `for` is supposed to point at the `id` attribute of the form element the label is associated with.

Comment: Last one. On the blur event handler of the input put the removal of the class inside a if condition checking if the there is no text inside the input element, only then should you remove the `.focus` class: `if(!$(this).val())`