# Label tag for more than 1 select tags

Tags: html

I am learning web development. I am at html forms.
I understand that we can use

```
<label>a:
<input type="text">
</label>
```

or same thing can be done like this

```
<label for="name">a:</label>
<input id="name" type="text">
```

for the selction of option say we want user to choose D.O.B from drop down menu Can we use the `<label>`tag
1st way:-

```
<label>Birthday:

<select><option>1<option><option>2<option></select>
<select><option>jan<option><option>feb<option></select>
<select><option>2001<option><option>2002<option></select>

</label>
```

OR

But how can we use this format what to use at `for=""`

```
<label for="birthday?????">Birthday:</label>
<select id="day"><option>1<option><option>2<option></select>
<select id="month"><option>jan<option><option>feb<option></select>
<select id="year"><option>2001<option><option>2002<option></select>
```

Comment: How would that work?

Comment: I mean label tags are meant so that screen readers can read it properly and we associate a label tag with id of the input element. but how can we associate a label tag with more than one select elements

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can an input field have two labels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829936/can-an-input-field-have-two-labels)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot associate a label element with more than one control. This is described in the [definition of label](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.9.1).

You could give each select element its own label.

A better approach is to have a single text input field for a date. Then there is no problem with label. It means more work, since you have to parse the data server-side, and you should also parse it client-side (for checks, so that the user can immediately be informed of problems). But it is better usability (surely it is faster to type in a date than to use three clumsy dropdowns) and better accessibility. You need to decide on a date format and clearly tell the user what the expected format is.

Answer (score 0):

A label associates some text with **one** input-field. So in your case you would have to split it up like this. You can also add a fieldset to group multiple formelements (and use legend to describe the gruop):

```
<fieldset>
 <legend> Enter your birthdate</legend>
 <label for="day">Day:</label>
 <select id="day"><option>1<option><option>2<option></select>
 <label for="month">Month:</label>
 <select id="month"><option>1<option><option>2<option></select>
 <label for="year">Year:</label>
 <select id="year"><option>1<option><option>2<option></select>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Thanks mate for clarification

Answer (score 0):

you can also use aria-labelledby and reverse the naming reference (which I think is a bit closer to the convention you were looking for):

```
    <label id="date">Check in date</label>
    <select aria-labelledby="date">
        <!-- ... -->
    </select> 
    <select aria-labelledby="date">
        <!-- ... -->
    </select> 
    <select aria-labelledby="date">
        <!-- ... -->
    </select>
```

or

```
    <label id="date">Check in date</label>
    <label for="day" id="label_day">Day</label>
    <select id="day" aria-labelledby="date label_day">
        <!-- ... -->
    </select> 
    <label for="month" id="label_month">Month</label>
    <select id="month" aria-labelledby="date label_month">
        <!-- ... -->
    </select> 
    <label for="year" id="label_year">Year</label>
    <select id="year" aria-labelledby="date label_year">
        <!-- ... -->
    </select>
```

Reference link :- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-labelledby_attribute